# Images pixelate even though they're the same size at the div

Tags: html, css, image

So I have my logo set up to 30px by 155px. This is exactly the size of my image. The image itself is not pixelated. And the div is set up to exactly the same size...

```
 .logo {
 height: 30px;
 width: 155px;
 background: url(logo.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

And yet, the logo looks very noticeably pixelated. Any ideas why this is happening? I feel like it's probably something dumb that I'm overlooking, but I'm totally stumped and have no clue.

Comment: Recreate the issue on jsfiddle

Comment: Can you please share a demo so that we can have a look at the issue and help you

Comment: My faint stab at this is - if the image was taken at one dpi and is displayed at a higher dpi - that can cause pixelation. So like the image is 72dpi but the screen is 96dpi. Try looking at the image with a paint program rather than something like Photoshop. If it looks bad there - it will probably look bad in the browser.